# Can I compare the Mean decrease in accuracy for two different random forest models

Tags: regression, machine-learning, logistic, random-forest

I am investigating how performance indicators measured in sporting contests relate to contest outcome.

Models produced through RF algorithms give the best results (measured as ability to predict outcome Win/lose) on both training data sets and 'future" data sets (compared to single trees and logistic regression).

I have 2 x data sets, a data set based on isolated data (looks at the data of each team without consideration to other team) and a relative data set (data of a team compared to opposition). As you'd expect relative data set gives the more accurate outcomes.

The purpose of my paper will be to compare the effectiveness of the models produced from relative and isolated data.

When I examine the mean decrease in accuracy for trees the top three predictors in the relative data set have values of 30-50%. In the isolated data set 9-15%.

My question - can I directly compare these, can I discuss the difference in magnitude? Can I refer to the fact that the relative PI's are more relevant than the isolated due to the magnitude differences?

If not what should I be using to discuss the importance of individual predictors and how would I compare models.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you find the _[a] mean decrease in accuracy for trees the top three predictors set have values of 30-50%. In the isolated data set 9-15%._? How do you define accuracy? How many predictors do you have? Why don't you (just) compare the full models (RFs) against each other?

Comment: Mean decrease in accuracy is a RF package produced output (R) that is based on out of bag error. I do intend to compare overall models, through prediction ability on future data (and caret package confusion matrix output - kappa statistic and p value). I have 11 predictors, I also want to talk about individual predictors (in a sports context) and I would like to use mean decrease in accuracy to this.